# Division of integers result in integer not in float? (Raptor Flowchart)

Tags: integer-division, flowchart, raptor

I want to draw a flowchart in Raptor, which will do division of integers and will give result in integers not in floating point numbers like: 2/5=2.5 but I want the result to be 2 which is the quotient part.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in Raptor, you'll want to use the floor or ceiling commands.  The floor command rounds down, while the ceiling rounds up.

They look like this: floor(x) and ceiling(x) where x is the value or variable you want to round up and down.

For floor, if x = 2.5, then it'll output 2

For ceiling, if x = 2.5, then it'll output 3

So, for instance if you wanted to take 5 and divide it by 2 and output the value rounded down, you'd enter:

```
floor(5/2)
```

which would output 2.

Hope this helps.